# Cannot delete property from Response nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im making a find request and get a response with the property "items" which is an array.
I dont want to send this array with the response at the end. I tried using delete object.items but its sending the property. Also setting the array to [] doesnt work.

**EDIT:**

oh yeah Im sorry. Im fetching the products with findById(). So category is not an array but an object. so i dont have to iterate through it. but the items porperty is not deleted. This is the actual code:

```js
    router.post('/products', auth, function (req, res) {
        var catId = req.body.catId;

        Category.getProductsOfCategory(catId, function (err, category) {
            if (err) {
                res.send({status: false, data: err})
            } else {

                if (category) {
                    // do not send items with the product
                        for (var i = 0; i < category.products.length; i++) {
                            var itemCount = 0;

                            // get only the count of items where no selldate was set
                            for (var k = 0; k < category.products[i].items.length; k++) {
                                if (!category.products[i].items[k].selldate) {
                                    itemCount++;
                                }
                            }

                            category.products[i].itemCount = itemCount;
                            delete category.products[i].items;
                        }



                    res.send({status: true, data: category.products})
                } else {
                    res.send({status: false, data: 'not found'})
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the real code? Because you're sending `category.products` in the end, which doesn't exist.

Comment: it does exist because i just want to send all products of the category. This is the model: var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    ts: {type: Number, required: true},
    icon: {type: String, required: true},
    products: [ProductSchema]
});

Comment: You're not reading it thoroughly. You've typed `category.products`. It doesn't exist. I suppose `category` is an array and there is no index in your `res.send`. It should be something like `category[0].products`.

Comment: There are mongoose objects, mongoose wraps the actual data. And hence delete does not work on them as intended.

Comment: But how can i exclude this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn `category` document into a plain object

```
if (category) {
    category = category.toObject() 
    // or 
    category = category._doc
    //...
}
```